# Как изменить формат веса в Magento?

Tags: magento

По умолчанию в Magento единица веса по некоторым мнениям просто цифра с последующей привязкой с способах доставки, а по второму мнению в фунтах. НО меня интересует как убрать все цифры после запятой вместе с ней?
Сейчас такая ситуация...[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
В файле price.phtml сделал вывод веса под ценой продукта.

```
<span class="regular-weight"> <?php $pro=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getEntityId()); ?>
                 <?php echo  $pro->getWeight(); ?><?php echo $this->__('гр');?>
            </span>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Функция getWeight возвращает строку. Поэтому столько нулей после запятой и сама запятая. Если хотите сами форматировать вывод переменной, то можно выполнить приведение к вещественному типу и далее выводить как душе угодно, например так:

```
<?php    
    $weight = (float) $pro->getWeight();
    $formattedWeight = number_format($weight, 2, ',', '');
    echo sprintf("%s %s", $formattedWeight, $this->__('гр'));
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<span class="regular-weight"> 
<?php $pro=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getEntityId()); ?>
                 <?php echo  number_format($pro->getWeight(),2,',',''); ?><?php echo $this->__('гр');?>
            </span>
```

Можно просто number_format использовать т.к. строка уже сформированна.

Answer (score 0):

Еще один вариант это использовать round()

например

$a = '7,0000000';

echo round($a);

будет просто 7 но если вес будет с десятичныит тогда уже приводить стоку к float и так же можно использовать round(*значение*, *кол-во символов после запятой*)